# "He was a considerable cut above the leagers" meaning

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, comprehension

What does the boldened part of this sentence mean?:

- As it turned out this man (a senior Foreign Affairs Advisor) was a **considerable cut** above the bush leaguers we had been dealing with.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the origin of "a cut above/below the rest"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/what-is-the-origin-of-a-cut-above-below-the-rest) (A vast etymological treatise, but one answer clearly gives the definition of 'a cut above'.)

Comment: You can also look up "bush league".

Answer (score 1):

It is an idiomatic expression:

be ***[a cut above](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20cut%20above)***

> better than other people or things

> - *All of his books are good, but this one is a cut above (the rest).
>   She's a cut above the other competitors and should win easily.*

(M-W)

- So the text means that *he was considerably better than other bush leaguers.*

Comment: He's not a bush leaguer; he's better than a bush leaguer. A *bush-leaguer* is a second-rate performer. [See dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/bush-leaguer).